# Laravel paginate is so slow

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a problem with pagination it's so slow in big data more than 25K rows
I try to get products saved by user in database by using:

```
$products = Item::has('product_save');
```

and I add same condition ...

```
$products = $products->where('active', 0);
```

I use this line to paginate :

```
$products = $products->paginate(20);
```

the all query take 0.06865 second.
but is so slow more than 4.9 seconds!
how i can make it very fast?

Comment: select only important fields rather than all  , may fast your query execution time

Comment: Can you check the generated query and post that here? This makes it easier to analyse the problem.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I'dont have lot of fields just 16 and I use it without relationship is so faster

Comment: @Jerodev how can get it from eloquent laravel?

Comment: The problem is just with pagination

Comment: @Jerodev th query is like this
select * from `products` where exists (select * from `product_saves` where `products`.`id` = `product_saves`.`product_id` and `user_id` = 2) and `price` between 0 and 999999999 and `wsell` between 0 and 999999999 and `ysell` between 0 and 999999999  In paginate 

$products = Item::has('product_save');

and I add same condition ...

$products = $products->where('active', 0);

I use this line to paginate :

$products = $products->paginate(20);

Comment: @cha7ta  , pagination query always takes more execution time than simple one , because it gives you extra information about paginaiton

Comment: What is the use of all those `between` parts in the query? I feel like this query can be optimized a lot.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry I use one query like it without has() just Item(); and it very fast! any suggestion?

Comment: @Jerodev just to filter samethings like price between 0 and 45

Comment: maybe this link  will help you, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: how I can do this 

SELECT p.* FROM `products` as p,product_saves as s where s.user_id=4 and p.id = s.product_id

Comment: the problem is in paginate
Total Execution Time: 0.001230001449585

Total Execution Time: 0.001399040222168

Total Execution Time: 2.4422662258148

Answer (score 0):

You asked 'how I can do this SELECT p.* FROM products as p,product_saves as s where s.user_id=4 and p.id = s.product_id' in the comments. Answer posted below:

```
Item::with('product_saves')->whereHas('product_saves', function($q){ 
    $q->where('user_id', 4)
});
```

The `and p.id = s.product_id` should be defined as the relationship product_saves, if not you should make a custom relationship for this. This will eager load the query and constrain your Item to only Items that have a product_saves relation as well as ensuring that the product_saves relation has a user_id of 4.

Comment: thanks, but when i use paginate it be so slow
first query run in
0.0012199878692627 S
with pagination 
5.9855120182037 S

Comment: Total Execution Time: 0.001230001449585

Total Execution Time: 2.4422662258148

Comment: That’s crazy. Pagination shouldn’t be slowing the query down that much. Have you tried using skip() and take() to emulate pagination to see if that helps?